# MLE for categorical distribution

Tags: probability

Referring to the picture, for each sample i in n, why do i only take the lambda for 1 class out of all k class instead of taking the product for the lambda's for all classes?

[image]

Comment: Why would you like to multiply them?

Comment: or rather for random variable $X$, since the pdf is given by $p(X|\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_k)=\Pi_{j = 1}^K {\lambda_j}$. for the purpose of MLE, i would get the following - $\Pi_{i = 1}^N\Pi_{j = 1}^K{\lambda_j}$ right? But from the expression in the formula it seem like i only keep $\lambda_j$ when, for a given $x_i$ it is of class $j$, while the other lambda terms for class $\ne$ j become 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A categorical random variable is such that has $k$ possible values that are exclusive. For example, say that there are three possible ways you could pick to go to work: bike, car, and public transportation. You would pick one of them on a given day with probabilities $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ respectively. The options are mutually exclusive, so probabilities are such that $\sum_{j=1}^3 \lambda_j = 1$. The probability mass function for the distribution of this random variable is

$$ \prod_{j=1}^3 \lambda_j^{\mathbf{1}(x_j = 1)}
$$

which is a smart way of saying that you pick an appropriate $\lambda_j$ and ignore the others.

For the likelihood function, it assumes that the observations are independent and identically distributed, so it is

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^3 \lambda_j^{\mathbf{1}(x_{ij} = 1)}
$$

There is *no* reason why you would multiply $\lambda_j$’s. We multiply the probabilities of independent events, while here we are talking about mutually exclusive ones.

Comment: oh ok i get it now, thanks for the clarification

Comment: If it answers your question, accept the answer so others know it is solved.